# Почему .NET 8.0 больше не доступен в Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

В январе этого года скачал Visual Studio 2022. При создании проекта на C# каждый раз предоставляется выбор платформы: NET 7.0 с долгосрочной поддержкой и NET 8.0 с поддержкой со стандартным сроком. Около месяца назад опция NET 8.0 исчезла и заменилась на NET 6.0. В интернете информации не нашёл. Никаких платных подписок у меня не было. [image: Сейчас меню выбора выглядит так]

Comment: На данный момент существует .NET6 и .NET7, версия 8 еще находится в превью, это все можете посмотреть на [офф. сайте](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet). Ну а превью версии всегда были доступны **только** на превью версии Visual Studio, об этом кстати также сказано на офф сайте [Visual Studio support: Visual Studio 2022 (v17.7 Preview 1)](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/8.0#:~:text=Visual%20Studio%202022%20(v17.7%20Preview%201)).